# Using WideCharToMultiByte on Windows Mobile

Tags: c++, unicode, windows-mobile

I have code designed for Win32 (XP and later) that I am porting to Windows Mobile 6. It contains this line:

```
int count = ::WideCharToMultiByte( CP_ACP, WC_NO_BEST_FIT_CHARS, ..., 0, 0 );
```

On Windows XP, this works fine, but on Windows Mobile it returns 0 and GetLastError() returns error 1004 "Invalid flags". `WC_NO_BEST_FIT_CHARS` is defined in winnls.h in the Windows Mobile 6 SDK.

This code will work in my limited tests if I either replace the call with `::wcstombs` or replace `WC_NO_BEST_FIT_CHARS` with 0.

I'd like to know what is the ramification of making either of those changes. Will this still work if I run my program on a Chinese or Russian version of Windows Mobile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows Mobile is based on Windows CE, and acording to the documentation, [WideCharToMultiByte does not support the flag WC_NO_BEST_FIT_CHARS in Windows CE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa450989.aspx).

According to that page, supported flags are:

```
WC_COMPOSITECHECK   Convert composite characters to precomposed characters.
WC_DISCARDNS        Discard nonspacing characters during conversion.
WC_SEPCHARS         Generate separate characters during conversion.
                    (This is the default conversion behavior).
WC_DEFAULTCHAR      Replace exceptions with the default character during conversion.
```